# List all the record counts along with file name

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file (displayed below) to get a count records along with the file name in a group of .csv files.

The batch file below will output the record count of the first .csv file. Is there a way to list all the record counts along with file name?

```
@echo off

for /F "tokens=3" %%f in ('find /V /C "-------------" *.csv') do (
echo %%f
)  >output.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off

(
 for %%n in (*.csv) do (
  for /F "tokens=3" %%f in ('find /V /C "-------------" "%%n"') do (
   echo %%n %%f
  )
 )
)  >output.txt
```

may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you too:

```
find /V /C "-------------" *.csv >output.txt
```

Or this:

```
@echo off
(for /F "tokens=1,*" %%f in ('find /V /C "-------------" *.csv') do echo(%%g)> output.txt
```